# Understanding a factorial function in python

Tags: c#, python

I'm trying to understand if the following Python function:

```
def factorial(i):
    if not hasattr(factorial, 'lstFactorial'):
        factorial.lstFactorial = [None] * 1000
    if factorial.lstFactorial[i] is None:
        iProduct = 1
        for iFactor in xrange(1, i+1):
            iProduct *= iFactor
        factorial.lstFactorial[i] = iProduct
    return factorial.lstFactorial[i]
```

would produce the same results as the equivalent in C#:

```
long factorial(long n) 
{ 
   return n <= 1 ? 1 : n * factorial(n-1);
}
```

for a value of 12 or less.

I know nothing about Python but have just converted some Python code to C#. This was the only function that I didn't fully understand.

Comment: why don't you just try and check ?

Comment: Why not install python?  It's a small MSI, takes less than 5 mins.  What's preventing that?

Comment: I can see why you're confused.  That's some pretty bad Python.  It's really badly thought out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is main algorithm

```
iProduct = 1
for iFactor in xrange(1, i+1):
    iProduct *= iFactor
```

other code is for caching results.

Answer (score 2):

Even without knowing Python, it must be clear to you that the two functions are far from identical. The C# version is calculating the factorial via recursion, whereas the Python one is doing it via iteration (although in a slightly weird way, with some odd memoization/caching going on - I guess in case you want to calculate multiple factorials in the lifetime of a program).

Anyway, since calculating a factorial is a very simple algorithm, it works out the same in both cases.

Comment: +1 for explaining that it uses memoization (which is correct), that is one of the solutions of speeding up the calculations, if the results have been already calculated in the past.

Answer (score 2):

IANAPG (Python Guru), but it looks to me like the function is creating a static array of 1000 entries, then filling them on an as-needed basis to prevent recalculation. In C++, it'd be something like:

```
long factorial(int i){
    //Cache array
    static long factorials[1000];
    if (!factorials[i]){ //If not cached, calculate & store
        int product = 1;
        for (int idx = 1; idx <= i + 1; ++idx){
            product *= idx;
        }
        factorials[i] = product;
    }
    return factorials[i]; //Return cached value
}
```

Comment: Be careful of the +1.  The python `xrange(a,b)` creates all values including a and b-1.  The idea is that `xrange` returns `b-a` distinct values. `xrange(1,5)` returns 4 values: 1, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: Fair enough - that's why I put the disclaimer up front. I've done a little python hacking, but not much.

Comment: Also, `long` is not long enough to hold values up to factorial(999). Already factorial(13) will overflow a signed 32-bit integer.

Comment: What, you expect me to give it *all* away for free? :-)

Answer (score 1):

it will return the same results, but the Python version will probably have better performance, because it memoizes the results

Comment: +1 for explaining that it uses memoization. However two solutions differ - C#'s solution uses recursion, while Python's does not.

Answer (score 1):

It just attaches an attribute called `lstFactorial` to `factorial`. This attribute is a list of 1000 values used to cache the results of previous calls.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def factorial(i):
    if not hasattr(factorial, 'lstFactorial'): #program checks whether caching list exists
        factorial.lstFactorial = [None] * 1000 #if so, it creates a list of thousand None elements (it is more or less equivalent to C/C++'s NULL
    if factorial.lstFactorial[i] is None: #prog checks if that factorial has been already calculated
        iProduct = 1 #set result to 1
        for iFactor in xrange(1, i+1): # C's for(iFactor = 1; iFactor &lt;= i+1; iFactor++)
            iProduct *= iFactor #we multiply result times current loop counter
        factorial.lstFactorial[i] = iProduct #and put result in caching list
    return factorial.lstFactorial[i] #after all, we return the result, calculated jest now or obtained from cache
```

To be honest, it is not the best algorithm, since it uses cache only partially.

The simple, user-friendly factorial function (no caching) would be:

```py
def factorial(i):
    if i == 0 or i == 1:
        return 1
    return i*factorial(i-1)
```

Of for lazy python programmers, most similiar to that C# example:

```py
f = lambda i: i and i*f(i-1) or 1
```

Comment: The problem with the recursive approach (which you may well be aware of, but mentioning this for the benefit of the OP), is that you will exceed the max recursion depth with high enough numbers.  (1000 by default in Python.)  Even if you used a version that passed an accumulator and did a tail call, you'd hit that limit since Python doesn't have tail call optimization.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. I should have written it in the answer, simply forgot about it. Sorry, and thanks for the remark. :)